# How do I fully charge my emulator battery?

Tags: battery, android-emulator

It bothers me to see half charged battery.

Anyone knows how I can fully charge it?

[image]

Comment: It's the little things that count ;¬)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can open a telnet connection to the AVD:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

then once connected:

```
power capacity 100
```

or

```
power status full
```

Source: [Android Developers: Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#power)